# How to perform Qaza salat (namaz)?

Tags: sharia, salat, salat-qada

I was wondering how can I perform my Qaza salat. I mean how many rakat salat do I have to pray for Fajr, Zuhr, Asr, Magrib and Isha. And what time do i have to perform it?

Comment: Please read the following article. [What is the ruling and condition for "Qaza Namaz"](http://islamhelpline.net/answer/6681). I found it to be a good one. Allah (SWT) knows best.

Answer (score 1):

The performance of them relatively is the same in the number of the Rek'ats and likewise in the circumstances. But you ought to change the intention (Niyyah) of them from Wajib to Qaza.

In regard to their time, I should mention that it is not Wajib that you definitely do them in their specified time. But perhaps it could be better if you do them on their specified time (or even it could be better you do them as soon as you can).

**To see more related questions/answers, and likewise asking your question:**

- http://www.islamquest.net/

Comment: Am I not supposed to pray only the farz and wajib rakats and leave out the sunnat and nafl?

Comment: At the initial stage, we should say our Wajib Salah, then strive to do our Qaza Salahs as soonas we can. Of course concerning nafile Salah (according to the viewpoint of Shiite), it is not Wajib to do them, but it is recommended as a good deed. Then I assume according to Islam, firstly u should do ur Wajib prayers, secondly do ur Qazas, thirdly do ur nafilahs as much as u can (as a recommended practice)

Answer (score 1):

With the intention to make up whichever salat you've missed, pray the qaza as soon as you can. There are some times when it's makrooh to offer salat (sunrise, sunset), other than that as AlSayed Ali mentioned, the sooner the better.

*Note: **Makruh** is not haram, but it is better not to do ...*